# Simple Non-Linear Programming Software

Tags: gratis, math, optimization

I have a non-linear maximization problem with < 12 constraints and < 12 variables. I'm looking for free simple software in which I can enter the expression to be maximized along with the constraints (no algorithm selection, gradient function, etc...).

For instance, a tool that lets me type in the problem like this...

> Maximize p = ax1^n + bx2^m ... subject to q <= r, z <= y ...

And returns p, x1, x2, ... would be ideal.

I found nothing online.  Either packages were not available, were broken or were hideously expensive.  The packages I tried in R required me to supply more information than I knew, like gradient functions.

I'm fine with online or offline software and any syntax.

As an example of the kind of stuff I'd love to find, here's a [linear programming tool available online](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/):

- gratis
- cross-platform
- support [nonlinear optimization](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Nonlinear-Programming.html)